# Processing TSV Files in Lua

Tags: string, csv, split, lua, lua-patterns

I have a very very large TSV file.  The first line is headers.  The following lines contain data followed by tabs or double-tabs if a field was blank otherwise the fields can contain alphanumerics or alphanumerics plus punctuation marks.

for example:

```
Field1<tab>Field2<tab>FieldN<newline>
```

The fields may contain spaces, punctuation or alphanumerics.  The only thing(s) that remains true are:

1. each field is followed by a tab except the last one
2. the last field is followed by a newline
3. blank fields are filled with a tab.  Like all other fields they are followed by a tab.  This makes them double-tab.

I've tried many combinations of pattern matching in lua and never get it quite right.  Typically the fields with punctuation (time and date fields) are the ones that get me.

I need the blank fields (the ones with double-tab) preserved so that the rest of the fields are always at the same index value.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: any own ideas? why do you have problems with punctuation if tabs separate your values? show us some of your attempts please. we don't like to just give code away

Comment: You could use pattern `\t?[^\t]*` to match both empty and non-empty data.  For example, if there are 3 columns in your file: `for col1, col2, col3 in tsv_string:gmatch"\t?([^\t]*)\t\t?([^\t]*)\t\t?([^\t]*)\n" do print(col1, col2, col3) end`

Comment: Sorry, I should have included code.  Here's where I am currently at:

for header in line:gmatch("[(%g\t)$]+") do

the problem is it matches the whole line instead of one tab separated field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
function test(s)
    local n=0
    s=s..'\t'
    for w in s:gmatch("(.-)\t") do
        n=n+1
        print(n,"["..w.."]")
    end
end

test("10\t20\t30\t\t50")
test("100\t200\t300\t\t500\t")
```

It adds a tab to the end of the string so that all fields are follow by a tab, even the last one.

Comment: This seems to be what I needed.  Thank you very much for the correction.  It's been several years since I've done any lua and I was never very good with the pattern matching in Lua.  My apologies for not posting code with my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Rows and columns are separated:

```
local filename = "big_tables.tsv"  -- tab separated values
-- local filename = "big_tables.csv" -- comma separated values

local lines = io.lines(filename) -- open file as lines
local tables = {} -- new table with columns and rows as tables[n_column][n_row]=value
for line in lines do -- row iterator
    local i = 1 -- first column
    for value in (string.gmatch(line, "[^%s]+")) do  -- tab separated values
--  for value in (string.gmatch(line, '%d[%d.]*')) do -- comma separated values
        tables[i]=tables[i]or{} -- if not column then create new one
        tables[i][#tables[i]+1]=tonumber(value) -- adding row value
        i=i+1 -- column iterator
    end
end
```